# Can I delete a file after it is read, or notify when all are processed?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

I have a list of files being read into Elasticsearch through Logstash. I wanted to know how to know when the files were all caught up.

I was thinking of deleting the file after it is fully read in.

I havent seen anything though in regards to notification or ack of file completion, or file deletion.
Id love some insight, as i figure it would be a part of the config file.  I just have no insight.

Ideally:  I would love delete the file after it is fully consumed.  That way, i can work my way through all of the file types, starting with txt files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `file` input in logstash you can do that, you need to change two config options, [`mode`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-mode) and [`file_completed_action`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html#plugins-inputs-file-file_completed_action).

You need to change the `mode` option to `read`, the default is `tail`, and add the `file_completed_action` with the value of `delete`.

```
file {
    mode => "read"
    path => "/path/to/your/files/*.log"
    file_completed_action => "delete"
}
```

Comment: Ah, ok.   Yeah, I was using tail originally which would read through the whole doc and (I think) then monitor the file for changes at the end.  So, This actually looks like it would make a lot of sense.